# How to turn off voice commands in my Audi MMI 3G+ for navigation?

Tags: audi, mmi

Every time when I press "i nav" button on the steering wheel I can hear the voice "navigation doesnt work". How can I turn it off? I am using that button to turn on carplay box menu, and every time it is annoying when I can hear that voice in the same time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a number of options outlined in the manual. From memory, the simplest is to press the button and say "Voice Guidance Off."

Another option is to use the volume control when the voice is speaking and take it down to zero - this mutes the navigation voice.

Comment: volume control mutes everything, not only navigation guidance. Voice guidance off? I will try it, But it needs to be set in english only, right?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk if it is saying “navigation doesn’t work” in English then probably… Unless you are translating the error message, which will be confusing…

Comment: yes, I translate error message from polish language... but I will check it and let you know within 20 minutes...

Comment: @SolarMike I changed to english and error says “navigation is not active”. MMI repeats it after me and I understand it is turned off, but I think it doesnt work because when I press “i nav” button again it still says “navigation is not active”.

Comment: volume control, when the voice is speaking **should** just mute that voice, not all audio